# Can't able to download Nokia PC Connectivity API

Tags: api, download, nokia

When i try to download API from Nokia website it returns 403 error: here is the download link : http://www.developer.nokia.com/Resources/Tools_and_downloads/Other/PC_Connectivity_API/

Please suggest me another download source or mail me. m.qayyum at live.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you were trying, may be Nokia server was very busy.
Now anyone can download the APIs once they sign in with the Nokia A/c.

If you still face the above mentioned problem, please download CCleaner application and run it. Then try downloading the APIs.

Comment: Yes now it is working...but i have already downloaded it from another website: http://dev.10086.cn/cmdn/wiki/index.php?doc-view-440.html